# Clone table, including primary keys, using ODBC and C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, odbc

Using ODBC and C# to work with a Microsoft Access database.

The following SQL query clones a table with field data types and sizes intact:

```
SELECT * INTO [NewTable] FROM [OldTable] WHERE 1=0;
```

Note that the `WHERE 1=0` ensures that only the schema, and not data, is copied. But primary key information in `NewTable` is missing and not carried over from `OldTable`. How is this done?

Comment: The `SELECT INTO` statement in no way intends to copy the schema, only the data. Not only the primary key will be missing, but also all the foreign keys, indexes, `NOT NULL` columns, etc...

Comment: Send a sql command to recreate the keys

Comment: Check: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/998711/how-to-copy-sql-table-with-primary-key

Comment: @RuiCaramalho useful link, but sadly that one is SQL Server specific